# Topic to Queue Mapping fails when trying to subscribe through C# API

Tags: c#, solace

I need to dynamically map Topic to queue through C# client API.

I have followed every step that is written in [https://solace.com/samples/solace-samples-dotnet/topic-to-queue-mapping/] and  Github sample [https://github.com/SolaceSamples/solace-samples-dotnet/blob/master/src/TopicToQueueMapping/TopicToQueueMapping.cs]. However everything works as expected until i hit the line

```
session.Subscribe(queue, tutorialTopic, SubscribeFlag.WaitForConfirm, null);
```

The API throws **Client_Fail** error and something in the line of unable to subscribe. Initially i thought that it could be the problem with the user not having the right permission. But even though the infrastructure team said that they have given the user all access including permission to bridge, I have hit a roadblock. What am I missing?

Comment: Can you provide the exact error you are receiving?